# How to implement button

Tags: flutter

[[image]]

I used the Elevated Button but I was not able to get the size of the button and to add the save icon in the middle.

Comment: please add a snippet code when asking for assistance. no one will give you a freshly baked code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IconButton.

```
IconButton(
           icon: Icon(Icons.save),
           onPressed: () {
            // some action
        },
    
 ),
```

or if you have to use custom icon/image on your button then

```
 GestureDetector(
          onTap: (){},
          child: Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage("path")))
          )
        )
```